# RPT file from CR10 on older version 8.5

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-8.5

My client use application that use Crystal Report 8.5 engine to print reports.
He wants to create new report in Crystal Report 10 and use it in his application.

Is there is any possibility to save report in CR 10 in 8.5 mode?

Comment: try to open it in 8.5 and save

Comment: it could help but i don't have 8.5 version

Comment: Then find it from net I guess.